# Using parse.com, can multiple, authenticated users access the same data?

Tags: parse-platform

How can I "pair" multiple users, and have them access the same data - perhaps some of the users in a group having read only rights? As a use case, think of a family sharing calendars, each using their own login, but being able to see each other's calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [Roles](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#roles) and [Security](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#security) in the Parse docs.
I'm no expert, but I would assume that you would create a role for a family and then restrict the access to either classes or objects (depending on your approach) with Access Control Lists. In that way you can have a group/role that has the same permissions for same objects and classes.

Adapted from the docs:

Creating a role

```
// By specifying no write privileges for the ACL, we can ensure the role cannot be altered.
var roleACL = new Parse.ACL();
roleACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
var familyRole = new Parse.Role("MyFamilyRole", roleACL);
familyRole.save();
```

Then

```
var calEvent = new Parse.Object("CalendarEvent");

var familyACL = new Parse.ACL();
familyACL.setPublicReadAccess(false)
familyACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false)
familyACL.setRoleReadAccess("MyFamilyRole", true);

calEvent.setACL(familyACL);
calEvent.save();
```

This can of course be done more efficiently by using defaultACLs and other functionality. But these are the basics.
Btw, I reference the JS api, since you didn't specify a platform.

Comment: Thank you, although it is still not clear to me how users are assigned to a family and how I get the familiACL for the currently logged in user, etc. In your example, a new familyACL is created, but in my use case it should be created once, for that family, and the ACL should then be stored and retrieved to be attached to other objects (e.g. calendar events)